# iOPhone: AdMob just blue banner with compass

Tags: iphone, admob

I'm trying to ingegrate AdMob in one of my free iPhone Apps. In my last Apps the integration seems to work fine and I got real banners from AdMob.
But at the moment I'm getting only a blue banner with a small compass icon. Looks like a test banner.
Is that okay? I deactivated the test-mode, but the banner is still the naked blue one.

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't create an empty house ad, this sounds like a bad creative being shown, not a problem on your end.  Hopefully you will see a different ad if you continue testing.